# ProviderNotFoundException (Error: Could not find the correct Provider<EntryProvider> above this HomePage Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, stateless, stateful

I am new in dart and I face this problem. I try to display data from provider entry_providers.dart but I got this problem
[the error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2aIc.png)

[this home.dart file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KR3g.png)

[this home.dart file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1skyY.png)

[this is the entry_providers.dart file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39wDZ.png)

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0):

In your main.dart file, you need to **initialize** and **propagate** your EntryProvider to all your sub-widgets:

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => EntryProvider()),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```